# How to use C/Obj-C variadic function in MacRuby?

Tags: macruby, variadic-templates

I declared a variadic function/method in a Obj-C class like this:

```
@interface Foo
+ (void) print: (id) firstMessage, ...;
@end

@implementation
+ (void) print: (id) firstMessage, ...{
    va_list ap
    va_start (ap, firstMessage)
    for (id message = firstMessage; message != nil; message = va_arg(ap, id)){
        NSLog(@"message: %@", message);
    }
    va_end(ap)
}
@end
```

This works on Obj-C function call like this:

```
[Foo print: @"Hello, world.", @"I'm Xavier.", nil];
```

The console would print:

```
=> Hello, world.
=> I'm Xavier.
```

But it doesn't work when I call the function call in MacRuby:

```
Foo.print (@"Hello, world.", @"I'm Xavier.", nil)
```

The console then prints:

```
=> Hello, world.
=> Hello, world.
=> (lldb)
```

Yes, it prints the first message twice! And then it crashes.

I found that the assignment "message = va_arg(ap, id)" doesn't work. The ***message*** obj doesn't not change. I thought it might be a problem within MacRuby (version 0.10).

I thought that MacRuby only takes the first argument and pass it to the Obj-C method. Doesn't it? Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to generate a bridge support file for your Objective-C class.

#### How?

You can find the full details on how to do this by reading the man page for `gen_bridge_metadata`. If your Obj-C class is part of a framework, using the `framework` method in MacRuby will also include the correct bridge support file. If you are linking directly, you may need to use `Kernel.load_bridge_support_file`.

#### Why?

MacRuby cannot infer from runtime metadata whether or not a method is variadic. This, combined with the fact that variadic methods have a different calling convention than non-variadic methods, means that MacRuby will always crash when calling a variadic method unless it is somehow informed ahead of time that it needs to use the variadic calling convention. This is what Bridge Support provides.